# Can this double sum be simplified?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Can this summation be simplified ($A$ is a constant)?

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{A} \displaystyle\sum_{j>i}^{A} f(i)f(j)$$

By simplified I mean either a closed-form expression in terms of $A$ and $f$, or failing that even just removing one of the sums.

If not, what if the $j>i$ is replaced by $j=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $$\sum_{i=1}^{A} \sum_{j>i}^{A} f(i)f(j)
  =\sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)\sum_{j=i+1}^{A} f(j)
  $$but you can also swap the indices:
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^{A} \sum_{j>i}^{A} f(i)f(j) =
  \sum_{j=1}^{A} f(j)\sum_{i=j+1}^{A} f(i)
  = \sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} f(j)
  $$
  Hence,
  $$
  2 \sum_{i=1}^{A} \sum_{j>i}^{A} f(i)f(j) =
  \sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)\sum_{j\neq i} f(j)
  =\sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^A f(j)\right)
  -f(i) \right]
  \\= \left(\sum_{j=1}^A f(j)\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)^2.
  $$
- $$\sum_{i=1}^{A} \sum_{j=1}^{A} f(i)f(j) = 
  \sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)\sum_{j=1}^{A} f(j) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^A f(j)\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer mookid. Could you please explain what you did on the second line: 
$\sum_{j=1}^{A} f(j)\sum_{i=j+1}^{A} f(i)
= \sum_{i=1}^{A} f(i)\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} f(j)$ 
I can follow the rest if that's correct.

Comment: you sum on indices such as $i>j$, and you can start with the sum according to $i$ or $j$.

Comment: I understand you have relabelled $i$ and $j$, but why is the sum from $j+1$ to $A$ equal to the sum from $1$ to $i-1$ (=$j-1$ after relabelling I think?) in the second summation over $f(j)$? Thanks.

Comment: Read my comment again. You make a sum of elements of, say, a matrix. The sum of the sum of the lines equals the sum of the  sum of the columns.

Comment: I totally get it now.